# Sending and Receiving Byte Array over TCP/IP in C

Tags: c, arrays, sockets, tcp, byte

I am relatively new to C-programming and have found no answer yet.
**I want to send and receive integers, chars and longs as bytes over a TCP connection correctly.**
I have built this, but it doesn't work yet.

**Sender:**

```
int a = 12345;
char b = -1;
unsigned long c = 12174723939;
unsigned char array[256];


array[0] = (a >> 0) & 0xFF;
array[1] = (a >> 8) & 0xFF;
array[2] = (b >> 16) & 0xFF;  //Is this correct for -1?
array[3] = (c >> 24) & 0xFF;
array[4] = (c >> 32) & 0xFF;
array[5] = (c >> 40) & 0xFF;
array[6] = (c >> 48) & 0xFF;

send(socket, array, sizeof(array),0);  //or is &array better?
```

**Receiver:**

```
int a;
char b;
unsigned long c;
unsigned char array[256];

recv(socket, array, sizeof(array),0);

a |= (array[0] << 0) & 0xFF;
a |= (array[1] << 8) & 0xFF;
b |= (array[2] << 16) & 0xFF;
c |= (array[3] << 24) & 0xFF;
c |= (array[4] << 32) & 0xFF;
c |= (array[5] << 40) & 0xFF;
c |= (array[6] << 48) & 0xFF;
```

Is this correct? What is missing? Is there any other solution?

How is it done with the receiving part? I've read about big and little endians (with **htonl/htons** and **ntohl/ntosl**). Does someone have an example on how to implement it, for example, in this code?

Comment: When running server and client on the same box, endianess is not an issue be definition.

Comment: @alk but design your software for future use is always well invested time. The step between "on same box" to "distributed version" is very short...

Comment: @LPs: I completely agree. I just wanted to hint, that "*it doesn't work*" might not be related to endianess.

Comment: You want to search for "marshalling" or "serialization".

Comment: So don't you want to tell  us *what* actually isn't working? What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: in the Receiver you'll need to initialize `a, b, c` to 0, or change the first line of their respective assignments to (for example) `a = (array[0] << 0) & 0xFF;` They'll start out with junk data, you'll be ORing in valid data with the junk which will result in junk.

Comment: You also want to take care in *detail* what `send()` and `recv()` return.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to need a long long if you want more than 32 bits in a single value.

Comment: @alk: I have the receiver on another machine. thats the problem

Answer (score 4):

What you have written is not correct. I assume that you intented to build an unsigned char buffer containing in that order:

- the two lowest byte of the representation of int value 12345
- a byte containing the representation of char value -1
- the 4 lowest bytes containing the representation of long value 12174723939

You should have written:

```
array[0] = (a >> 0) & 0xFF;  // lowest byte
array[1] = (a >> 8) & 0xFF;  // next
array[2] = b;   // cast a char to an unsigned char
array[3] = (c >> 0) & 0xFF;  // lowest byte of c
array[4] = (c >> 8) & 0xFF;
array[5] = (c >> 16) & 0xFF;
array[6] = (c >> 24) & 0xFF;
```

And you should not send the whole buffer but only the interesting part: 7 bytes:

```
send(socket, array, 7, 0);
```

In the receiver part, you rebuild the values from their bytes:

```
a = array[0];  // start with an initial value
a |= array[1] >> 8;
b = array[2];  // is already a single byte
c = array[3];
c |= array[4] >> 8;
c |= array[5] >> 16;
c |= array[6] >> 24;
```

Note: as you explictely deal with endianness by sending the lowest byte first, this could be used across machines using different endiannesses

Comment: i tried it out and two things didnt work yet:
- casting a char to an unsigned char. when i print out these values they are 255 (for -1) and 254 (for -2). i think thats fine so far. but on the other side i dont receive those values always. sometimes when i send different negative values i get positive values instead. do you know why?
- storing the array values in new variables works better with `<<` instead of `>>`. im working with for-routines and maybe i have some calculation issues as well.

Comment: @Frechdachs: 0xFF (or 255) is the representation in 2 complement of `(char) -1`. Said differently `(unsigned char) 255` and `(signed char) -1` share the same binary representation : `0xFF`.

Comment: Bellesta: so there is no chance to see if i receive a `-1` or `255`? my code below is what i have for now.

Answer (score 1):

On the receiver side you should think in reverse order

```
a += array[1];
a<<=8;
a += (array[0]);
```

But take note that left shift signed value is UB as standards says

> **6.5.7.4**
>
> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
>       zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo
>       one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed
>       type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is
>       the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: thank you. so i have to start at the last byte of the whole array and go backwards to the first right?